# How do I send information from a binary file to the screen AND external file?

Tags: c++, function, struct, binary, binaryfiles

In one of my projects, I must read 4 separate structs from my binary file and then send the information to the screen and external file. Can someone please instruct me on how to do this? I believe I have already read the files.

Also, when I compile and run the program, I give the user and option to continue (a simple do while 'Y'). In case the user enters an invalid character, I would like Invalid response. Please answer 'Y' for  Yes and 'N' for no" to appear. It does this indeed BUT, after that is outputted, System ("PAUSE") will take its course and press any to continue will show up indicating the termination of the pogram. I am confused as to why so can someone aid me there also. If I enter Y or N it will exit the program.

Thank you so much

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 12;


struct Division
{
char divName [SIZE];
double sales [4];
};

int main()
{
Division Div_E; 
Division Div_W; 
Division Div_N; 
Division Div_S;

void Describe_Program ();
void Create_Corporate_File (Division& mainDiv);
void Display_Corporate_Sales (Division& Div_E, Division& Div_W, Division& Div_N, Division& Div_S);


Describe_Program();
         string Div; 
         char ans;
do
{  
    cout << "Enter the name of the division: \n";
    getline (cin,Div); 
     cin.ignore();
        if (Div == "East")
        {  
                Create_Corporate_File (Div_E);
                }      

        else if (Div == "West")
        { 
             Create_Corporate_File (Div_W);
             }
        else if (Div == "North")
        {
             Create_Corporate_File (Div_N);
             }
        else if (Div == "South")
        {
             Create_Corporate_File (Div_S);
             }
             else 
             {

              }

             cout << "\nWould you like to continue? (Y/N)--\n";  

              cin>>ans; 
              ans = toupper (ans);
               if (ans != 'Y' && ans != 'N')
               {
                       cout << "Invalid response. Please answer 'Y' for \n"; 
                       cout << "Yes and 'N' for no.\n" <<endl; 
                       } 

//cin.ignore();


}
        while (ans == 'Y');      

//Display_Corporate_Sales(Div_E, Div_W, Div_N, Div_S); 
system ("PAUSE");
return 0; 
}


void Describe_Program()
{ 
    cout << "This program will prompt you to enter the sales amount\n";
    cout << "for each quarter of the North, South, West and East Division.\n";
    cout << "After you enter the sales amount for each quarter, the program\n";
    cout << "will be able to calculate the total quarterly sales for that";
    cout << "division"; 
    cout << endl<<endl; 
         return; 
} 

void Create_Corporate_File (Division& mainDiv)
{
     fstream quarterly_sales; 
     quarterly_sales.open ("quarterly_sales.dat" , ios::out|ios::binary);

          for(int sales = 0; sales < 4; sales++)
          {         
    cout << "Please enter the sales amount for quarter " << sales + 1 <<":\n";
    cin >> mainDiv.sales [sales]; 
        }


     quarterly_sales.write((char*)(&mainDiv), sizeof(mainDiv));
     quarterly_sales.close (); 
}

void Display_Corporate_Sales (Division& Div_E, Division& Div_W, Division& Div_N, Division& Div_S)
{
     fstream quarterly_sales; 
     quarterly_sales.open ("quarterly_sales.dat" , ios::in|ios::binary);      


     quarterly_sales.read ((char *)(&Div_E), sizeof(&Div_E));
     cout << Div_E.divName ;
     cout << Div_E.sales[0];  

     quarterly_sales.read (reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Div_W), sizeof(&Div_W))
     cout << Div_W.divName ;
     cout << Div_W.sales[0];   

     quarterly_sales.read (reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Div_N), sizeof(&Div_N))
     cout << Div_N.divName ;
     cout << Div_N.sales[0];   

     quarterly_sales.read (reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Div_S), sizeof(&Div_S))
     cout << Div_S.divName ;
     cout << Div_S.sales[0];   


    quarterly_sales.close(); 
    return; 
     }
```

Comment: I don't understand, where is your confusion?  Can you send to `cout`?  If you can send to `cout`, you can send to a file.

Comment: Send first the the console, then to the file.  It may appear to send to both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not planning on giving you the code answer to your homework, the commands you are looking for are cout (to write to screen) and file IO commands (see the following link and the example that appears under "Text Files"):

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/